# pgfplots: How to hide "nodes near coords" if value is 0 (empty)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes-near-coords, ybar

Assumed we have this **Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xtick                   = data,
            ymin                    = 0,
            symbolic x coords       = {Bar 1, Bar 2, Bar 3},
            nodes near coords,
            ]

            \addplot coordinates {(Bar 1, 50) (Bar 2, 0) (Bar 3, 50)};%
        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

As you can see, there is some ugly "0" at the middle `ybar`. How can I avoid/hide `nodes near coords` if their corresponding value is `0`, so the displayed number should be invisible?

Comment: I do think that this is "ugly" since it shows the reader that the value is actually zero and not just small.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Actually there was no measurement value taken for `Bar 2`, so I want to hide the `0`. In reality this is a multi coord diagram, so don't wonder about my silly question please. :-)

Comment: Why is there a "Bar 2" at all in this case then?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: The real diagram consists of 11 `ybars`, separated into five `symbolic x coords` while coords 1 - 3 have three ybars each, coords 4 and 5 only have one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little roundabout perhaps, but this seems to work:

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xtick                   = data,
            ymin                    = 0,
            symbolic x coords       = {Bar 1, Bar 2, Bar 3},
            visualization depends on={y\as\YY},
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\YY}{ifthenelse(\YY==0,0,1)}\ifnum\YY=0\else\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\fi},
            ]

            \addplot coordinates {(Bar 1, 50) (Bar 2, 0) (Bar 3, 50)};%
        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something similar but I struggled (`-->` does not work) with the logic test.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{xifthen}

% Instiration
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36114
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275187

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        xtick = data,
        ymin = 0,
        symbolic x coords = {Bar 1, Bar 2, Bar 3},
        visualization depends on={rawy \as \myRawy},
        nodes near coords = {
        \ifthenelse{<Logic Test>} % something like '\myRawy < 0.001'
            {<True Case>} % Do nothing
            {<False Case>} % Print \myRawy
        },
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {(Bar 1, 50) (Bar 2, 0) (Bar 3, 50)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Maybe someone here can solve it elegantly.

Comment: The problem is that `\myRawy` is a decimal number, but the test only works on integers. So if you do `\ifthenelse{\myRawy==0}...` the test becomes `50.0==0`, and it chokes on the `.` because it expects an integer. That's why I did the extra step with `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` and the `ifthenelse` before the `\ifnum` test.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. Do you know if there are functions in tikz that allow to avoid this workarounds? Like a comparison that supports floats.

Comment: Well, `pgfmath`s `ifthenelse` function does support floats, but if I remember correctly I couldn't get that working directly, because `\pgfmathprintnumber` choked on the empty string I used as the output for the zero case. That's why I first checked the y-value with pgfs `ifthenelse` and secondly used `\ifnum` to decide what to print.